# Compartilhar documento (PDF, JPG e etc) Cordova

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, mobile

Alguem sabe como faço para compartilhar um documento utilizando cordova? um documento que eu tenha no meu celular (seja temporario ou nao). Gostaria de enviar (que nao seja o link) e sim o documento em si.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o meu problema utilizando o plugin [SocialSharing](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin)

```
var options = {
  files: ['arquivo.png'],
  chooserTitle: 'APP'
}

var onSuccess = function(result) {
  console.log("Share completed? " + result.completed); // On Android apps mostly return false even while it's true
  console.log("Shared to app: " + result.app); // On Android result.app is currently empty. On iOS it's empty when sharing is cancelled (result.completed=false)
}

var onError = function(msg) {
  console.log("Sharing failed with message: " + msg);
}

window.plugins.socialsharing.shareWithOptions(options, onSuccess, onError);
```